# Как решить проблему с Unity?

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Пожалуйста по одной проблеме. Я ввёл строку :

```
Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverLapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.2f);
```

А программа отвечает:

```
 "error CS0117:'Physics2D' does not contain a definition for 'OverLapCircleAll'"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть вопрос, поскольку опечатки не несут никакой пользы сообществу.

Comment: @CrazyElf при этом сам ответил на вопрос, чтобы заработать рейтинг. Класс!))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да я фиг знает как тут правильно сделать, задавшему вопрос ответ всё же нужен, но в целом сообществу пользы не будет )

Comment: @CrazyElf МНе кажется, Вопрос однозначно следует закрыть, так как он абсолютно точно соответствует проблеме: `Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям.`

Comment: @МаксимФисман Ну я то проголосовал

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто именно вы написали `я фиг знает как тут правильно сделать` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция называется [OverlapCircleAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html), регистр букв важен.

У вас же `OverLap` с большой буквой `L`.